# Specializing RSS content

Tags: html, rss

May I please have some help in using an RSS feed.

Here is a link to an RSS feed: http://weather.uk.msn.com/RSS.aspx?wealocations=wc:NZXX0049&weadegreetype=C&culture=en-GB

This is the feed that I am looking for. The problem is, how can I get information on other locations rather than just Wellington New Zealand. I am having trouble finding the page that lets me specify the region for the RSS feed.

If anyone has some time to quickly point me in the correct direction, I would appreciate it greatly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

goto http://weather.uk.msn.com/, search the location, e.g., London. It will go to URL like http://weather.uk.msn.com/local.aspx?wealocations=wc:UKXX0085&q=London%2c+England, copy parameters wealocatioins (wc:UKXX0085) and replace wc:NZXX0049 in the URL you provided.